# User authentication middleware implementation - Razor pages

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web, razor-pages, asp.net-core-middleware

I using razor pages for web development and i new to the architecture aspects of web development. Trying to get some opinions and learn here.

There is no login page

1. I am trying to implement middleware for authorization, is this is a better and relevant way to do it? or is there something better or appropriate that i can use?
2. Can i use this middleware in the all pages in the site?
3. How i can make sure that the user is authorized, when the user access the page directly using the routes? instead of going through the home page?

Thanks in advance for any advices!

Researching, trying different ways to implement it through the code.

Comment: Have you looked into Microsoft's Identity?

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper no, i haven't but i checked now. I dont think my org has a different setup for this, which most of the other applications use.

Comment: Hi,@mis.gg6144 there already contains the middleware app.UseAuthentication/ app.UseAuthorization in asp.net core ,what you need to do is configure the options when regist the related service,you could check this doucment for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Thank you, i was wondering about what those things do. I will look into it.